# Cassandra won't replicate data to new DC

Tags: cassandra

I have a single-node Cassandra 3.11.4 setup in one datacenter.

I know that is awful, and wrong, so I am trying to fix it by moving the data to a 3-node setup in another datacenter.

Taking a snapshot and copying it over means too much downtime, so I am trying to add the 3 new nodes to the cluster and have Cassandra replicate the data over.

The strategy for my user keyspace, as well as `system_distributed`, `system_auth` and `system_traces` is this:
`{'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', '(newdc)': '3', '(olddc)': '1'}`

All nodes see each other properly (1 in the old datacenter, 3 in the new).
All nodes report UN.
All nodes report 100% effective ownership.
I can query my keyspace from any node and get data back.
There is a folder for my user keyspace in the data folder on the new nodes, but it is empty.
The new nodes show <1MB load, which seems a bit low compared to the 600GB+ from the original.

When I do `nodetool rebuild -- (olddc)` on any of the new nodes, it returns almost immediately without any message. That's the command everyone tells me is supposed to actually move the data, but no dice.

How do I get the data to actually replicate over?

In the log, I get `Some ranges in (...all my ranges...) are already available, skipping streaming these ranges`. Available yes, I'd actually like the node to have the data though!

`nodetool status` shows this:

```
Datacenter: (new)
==================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  XX.XXX.X.110  775.49 KiB  256          100.0%            XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX  Unknown
UN  XX.XXX.X.109  929.93 KiB  256          100.0%            XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX  Unknown
UN  XX.XXX.X.108  710.75 KiB  256          100.0%            XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX  Unknown
Datacenter: (old)
=============================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  XXX.XX.X.233  676.17 GiB  256          100.0%            XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX  Unknown
```

Comment: i am not familiar with your software, but it looks like an  similar thing like [here](https://medium.com/building-the-open-data-stack/how-to-migrate-your-cassandra-database-to-kubernetes-with-zero-downtime-f824f5bbf50b) where someone also wanted to add an additional cluster. please remind to create backup before doing any actions. if i understood the current point, you did not yet replicate the data to the other nodes

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/338035/cassandra-wont-replicate-data-to-new-dc

Comment: im greatly to see, that you got the right sight, but for now please respect, that crossposting is not an option ;)